# AUCTeX preview breaks if monitor orientation isn't normal or inverted

Tags: auctex, preview-latex, previewing

When I use AUCTeX's preview feature on a monitor who's orientation is normal or inverted (i.e. rotated either 0 or 180 degrees) then everything works perfectly and the png files from the resulting `_region_` folder look nice:

> [image: good_preview].

However, as soon as I try and generate the preview images on a monitor who's orientation is left or right (i.e. rotated either 90 or 270 degrees) then the png files from the resulting `_region_` folder look all squashed:

> [image: bad_preview].

If I use two monitors simultaneously then the results will depend upon which monitor the Emacs window is currently in; I find it surprising that the window position can even affect the result of such a feature. I have disabled all custom configuration on my Emacs, tried multiple desktop environments and even swapped monitor but the problem persists.

**At what point could the orientation of my monitor affect AUCTeX's preview function and how I can fix the problem?**